# Find all users external to Google Apps domain in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I'm looking to find all files and folders in our company google drive owned by users external to our domain. We've had a number of interns over the last couple years that have created documents and folders that aren't under our control and can't be managed by our domain. This is a problem for obvious reasons, but there seems to be no easy way for us to crawl out of the darkness.

I've tried using [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GoogleDriveManagement), but GAM can't 'see' these files owned by these users. Otherwise I could take a list of all interns emails and search for files owned by them and create copies or do other mass changes.

The [Google Drive Recursive Ownership](https://github.com/davidstrauss/google-drive-recursive-ownership) tool could potentially be used to find files owned by specific users and then create copies, but it would require a little bit of programming to work through.

Is there any straightforward way to fix this issue?

Comment: Looks that you already found a solution but it's not clear to me what is the issue that you want to fix. Are you looking for a workaround to the "little bit of programming"?